# NextJS App Router React Testing Library Tests - ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a simple NextJS app router:

Users Page `/users

```
async function getUsers() {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
    const data = await fetch(url)

    if (!data.ok) {
        // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
      }

    return data.json();

}


export default async function Users() {
    const users = await getUsers();

    return (
       <>
        <h1>Users</h1>
        <ul>
            {users.map(user => (
                    <li key={user.id}>
                        {user.name}
                    </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
       </>
    )
}
```

and here is the test; it's configured with jest and react testing library

```
// dependencies
import {screen, render} from '@testing-library/react'

// page
import UsersPage from 'src/app/users/page';

describe('', () => {
    it('should render the users page', async () => {
        render(
            await UsersPage()
        )
    })
})
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Not sure what to do here, do I need to import a library for this.

I could just put the fetch function in a separate file and just use `jest.mock` for that file; which is the proper way in a real world application.

However, I'm very curious how to test this app router in this setup, with the fetch function in the same file. Can anyone give me some pointers on to resolve the error?

Also, is this the correct way to render an async function component in NextJS App Router?

```
render(
            await UsersPage()
        )
```

If I do this instead:

```
render(<UsersPage />
```

This spits out an error

`[Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])`

This is coming from the `async` keyword. Solution to resolve this error, either remove the `async` in the app router function or do an await in the test. It seems to be an issue in React Testing Library - [issue](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1209)

Looking forward to your help, thanks!!